# WiX Toolset v4: Dynamically set Target/Ouput Name of installer

Tags: wix, wix4

After upgrading a WiX installer project (.wixproj) file to v4, the MSBuild step in the project to set the TargetName of the installer file output is no longer working.

I would like to dynamically append the assembly version of the application to be installed to the TargetName of the msi file name i.e. `MyApplication.X.X.X.X.msi`.

Below is a snippet of the .wixproj file in its current state (I have removed some code for the sake of brevity):

```
<Project InitialTargets="SetVersion;BeforeBuild;CopyLinkedContentFiles">
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="4.0.0-rc.1" />
  [...]
  <Target Name="SetVersion">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Assembly" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(SolutionName).%(Assembly.Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=%(Assembly.Version)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="4.0.0-rc.1" />
  [...]
</Project>
```

The .wixproj previous had the following code to adjust the `TargetName`:

```
<Target Name="SetVersion">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
            <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
            <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
            <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
            <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
            <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\..\OCS.Service\</SolutionDir>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe">
            <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=%(AssemblyVersion.Version)</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetName>$(SolutionName).%(AssemblyVersion.Version)</TargetName>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
```

The latter solution worked as expected prior to upgrading to v4, however, upon building the project and inspecting the output of the build, the change to the `TargetName` have not been applied.

Answer (score 1):

I posed the question on the WiX discussion site (https://github.com/orgs/wixtoolset/discussions/7317#discussioncomment-5445882) and the answer was that WiX4 does not use TargetName et al.

I took the easy way out and set outputname to a known value. After the build I copy the installer & it's pdb using the pattern I desire, then I delete the known name.

So at the top of with wix4 project file:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputName>xyzzy</OutputName>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

and at the bottom:

```
    <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="4.0.0-rc.4" />
    
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <!-- Get the programs assembly version from the .exe file -->
        <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)SystemMonitorService.2012\$(OutputPath)SystemMonitorService.exe">
            <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AsmInfo" />
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>
        <!-- Store the assembly version number in ProductVersion preprocessor variable -->
        <CreateProperty Value="$(DefineConstants);ProductVersion=%(AsmInfo.Version)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
        </CreateProperty>
    </Target>
    
    <Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
        <!-- Name the .msi file after the solution configuration and assembly version e.g TestService-DebugAll-1.4.0.0.msi -->
        <CreateProperty Value="$(SolutionName)-$(Configuration)-%(AsmInfo.Version)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="NewOutputName" />
        </CreateProperty>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\xyzzy.msi" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(NewOutputName).msi" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\xyzzy.wixpdb" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(NewOutputName).wixpdb" />
        <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)bin\xyzzy.msi" />
        <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)bin\xyzzy.wixpdb" />
    </Target>
```

which gives me my desired output of "Optimiser.2012-Debug-2.125.0.0.msi" (and the corresponding wixpdb)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add `TargetName` property in property group will suffice.

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SetupKitVersion>1.2.3.4</SetupKitVersion>
    <TargetName>MyProductSetup_$(SetupKitVersion)_$(Configuration)</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

To customize the leading name, you can add another property:

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SetupKitName>MyProductSetup</SetupKitName>
    <SetupKitVersion>1.2.3.4</SetupKitVersion>
    <TargetName>$(SetupKitName)_$(SetupKitVersion)_$(Configuration)</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

and, use the following build command:

```
dotnet build -p:InstallerPlatform=x64 -p:SetupKitName="NewProduct.Setup" -p:SetupKitVersion=2.2.2.2 myproduct_setup.wixproj -o publish/
```

ref: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/8c757c0f67f26f21c6bcbbfb81b7ea8b91c35fe4/src/wix/WixToolset.Sdk/tools/wix.targets#L685